# PrimeFaces InputNumberRenderer Exception

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces in my Java code as follows:

```
HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) event.getComponent();

InputNumber inputNumber = new InputNumber();
inputNumber.setId("input");

form.getChildren().add(inputNumber);
```

And it gives the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.primefaces.component.inputnumber.InputNumberRenderer.renderAccessibilityAttributes(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIInput;)V

What could it be caused by?

Comment: Your runtime classpath is polluted with multiple different versioned PrimeFaces libraries in the runtime classpath which are conflicting each other.

Comment: @BalusC I had Primefaces 5.2 earlier. Since org.primefaces.component didn't have the class InputNumber, I changed it to Primefaces 7.0. I've removed the older version of Primefaces library.But still facing the same  issue. What is the solution?

Comment: Your **runtime** classpath (in the deployment), check that too... Do a clean build etc...

Comment: @Kukeltje tried that too. But the issue is still alive!

Comment: Oh and it might maybe also mean that you compiletime use a newer PF version then runtime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue.

```
HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) event.getComponent();
InputNumber inputNumber = new InputNumber();

inputNumber.setId("input1");
ValueExpression inputNumberValue = ef.createValueExpression(
context.getELContext(), "#{ruleManagedBean.inputNumber}",
Double.class);
inputNumber.setValueExpression("value", inputNumberValue);

form.getChildren().add(inputNumber);
```

And in xhtml file:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <f:event type="postAddToView"
        listener="#{ruleManagedBean.populateForm}" />
        <pe:blockUI></pe:blockUI>
</h:form>
```

**Note**:Primefaces Extension(PE) 4.0 jar is used for InputNumber. So I had to include an empty PE tag(I used pe:blockUI) because it seems like PE js files are not included unless it has at least one PE tag.

Comment: I have no clue what you actually did version wise, code wise... Sorry, can you elaborate?

Comment: I assume `id` attribute must not have `input` as value so he changed it to `input1`. I ran across an issue like this when your value has a name conflict with any internal attribute of a component.

Comment: @djmj No, that wasn't the issue. I had set id=input1 earlier.